# Two SUMS with Different Grouping

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I have two tables, GameLog and Players:

GameLog:

```
Player_ID, Team, FGA, Date_Played
```

Players:

```
Player_ID, FirstName, LastName
```

I have two queries that SUM the FGA and then groups them by team and by player, respectively:

```
SELECT gl.Tm, SUM(gl.FGA) As TmFGA, gl.Date_Played
FROM GameLog gl
GROUP BY gl.Date_Played, gl.Tm;
```

Which gives the result:

```
Team     TmFGA     Date_Played
GSW      84        2/26/2014
UTA      74        2/26/2014
```

And then:

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, gl.Tm, SUM(gl.FGA) AS FGA, gl.Date_Played
FROM GameLog AS gl INNER JOIN Players AS p ON p.Player_ID = gl.Player_ID
GROUP BY gl.Date_Played, gl.Tm, p.LastName, p.FirstName;
```

Which gives the result:

```
FirstName     Lastname     Team     FGA     Date_Played
Andrew        Bogut        GSW      5       2/26/2014
Steve         Blake        GSW      6       2/26/2014
Derrick       Favors       UTA      7       2/26/2014
```

Obviously those are partial results, but you get the idea.

The end goal is one query that performs a calculation on the FGA compared to the total FGA of the team, but step one is getting both FGA for the player and the total FGA for his team into the same query.

So the first step for now would be to get results like this:

```
FirstName     LastName     Team     FGA     TmFGA     Date_Played
Andrew        Bogut        GSW      5       84        2/26/2014
Steve         Blake        GSW      6       84        2/26/2014
Derrick       Favors       UTA      7       74        2/26/2014
```

As a side note, whenever I run the Player specific query, I get a prompt asking for "Query1.FirstName". When I just click OK it runs, but any idea why I get this prompt?

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT y.FirstName, y.LastName, y.Tm, y.FGA, y.Date_Played,x.TmFGA FROM
(SELECT p.FirstName as FirstName, p.LastName as LastName, gl.Tm as Tm, SUM(gl.FGA) AS FGA,
        gl.Date_Played as Date_Played
FROM GameLog AS gl INNER JOIN Players AS p ON p.Player_ID = gl.Player_ID
     GROUP BY gl.Date_Played, gl.Tm, p.LastName, p.FirstName)y
JOIN 
(SELECT Tm, SUM(FGA) As TmFGA, Date_Played
FROM GameLog 
GROUP BY Date_Played, Tm)x
ON x.Tm=y.Tm
```

Comment: This seems close, but I'm getting a syntax error on the last JOIN. Do I need parentheses of some sort around the two JOINs?

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'p.FirstName JOIN (Select Tm, Sum(FGA) As TmFGA Date_Played FROM GameLog GROUP BY Date_Played, Tm) x ON x.Tm=gl.Tm'

Comment: Closer. First thing I noticed is last line should be ON x.Tm=y.Tm. Now it's running but not getting the TmFGA, and when I click Run it asks me to enter a paramater value for x.TmFGA

Comment: You have a prompt variable see here http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/use-parameters-to-ask-for-input-when-running-a-query-HA102809759.aspx As to why it doesnt get TmGFA I dont see it.